# Integrating nodejs with javaee application

Tags: node.js, jakarta-ee, browser

I have to develop an on demand streaming platform (Video On demand) and for streaming i would like to use nodejs to control the streamed content ,and i want to know if i have to convert videos to ather formats to get supported by all browsers, Thank you

Comment: How does this relate to Java EE?

Comment: I want nodejs to handle file uploading and streaming on demand because the application developement technology is javaee, Thank You